# Gap between sections in single page website

Tags: html, css, grid

Hi i'm trying to create a single page website with various sections. However, when I try to create two sections, there seems to be an auto margin between them. I tried to fix it by defining margin:0 for all sections but that doesn't do the trick.

Here's the link: http://alchuang.com/indexnav.html

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Relevant code:

```
<section style="background-color:white">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>helllllllo</h1>    
  </div>
</section>

<section style="background-color:red">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>helllllllo</h1>    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: reset margin for hx and p to 0 and see gap fading away :)

Answer (score 1):

Heading elements have a default margin. Add `margin:0` to your h1 rule.

Comment: wow. that was quick. I was a dummy, I should have added container within the sections, that solved it. Thanks

Comment: if that answer helped you, you can help the community by accepting it as a correct answer. :)